# Concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a query to concatenate column values from multiple rows based in an ID column.

This is the structure of my table:

```
ID      Level

000      C
000      FK
111      F
222      FN
222      C
333      F
333      C 
444      C
```

The expected result should be like this:

```
ID      Level

000      C - FK
111      F
222      FN - C
333      F - C
444      C
```

How can I do this in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: What happens if there are more than two rows for an ID? And how do you decide which order the values come in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `level` really your column name? Anyway, use `listagg`:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, c_level) as
  2    (select '000', 'C'  from dual union all
  3     select '000', 'FK' from dual union all
  4     select '111', 'F'  from dual union all
  5     select '222', 'FN' from dual union all
  6     select '222', 'C'  from dual union all
  7     select '333', 'F'  from dual union all
  8     select '333', 'C'  from dual union all
  9     select '444', 'C'  from dual
 10    )
```

Query:

```
 11  select id,
 12    listagg(c_level, ' - ') within group (order by null) result
 13  from test
 14  group by id
 15  order by id;

ID  RESULT
--- ----------
000 C - FK
111 F
222 FN - C
333 F - C
444 C

SQL>
```